# Convert sql query to EF

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Can anybody please help with this SQL query to transform it to EF Linq Expression?

```
select MI.Id, B.Count, B.Cost, Name, Price, Unity, I.Count, I.Cost, BOL.Date, BOL.type, BOL.Number
        from Balance B inner join MaterialsInfo MI on Mi.Id = B.MaterialsId
        inner join Income I on MI.Id = I.MaterialsId
        inner join BillOfLading BOL on I.BillOfLadingId = BOL.Id

        where B.Id in (select Id from (select max(Date), Id from Balance group by Balance.MaterialsId))

        and I.Id in (select Id from(select max(Date), Income.Id as Id from Income inner join BillOfLading BOL on Income.BillOfLadingId = BOL.Id group by Income.MaterialsId))
```

I've been trying to do this for days, so I could really use some help.

Do you need extra info?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**
Here is a little part of the diagram, maybe it helps
[image: DB diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the subqueries in both of your conditions in where clause is incorrect. Because your

> **group by column is missing in the select statement**

And it is very unclear what you trying to achieve from the subqueries.

Without a clear understanding of your subqueries, all I can prepare for you is this.

```
var result = await (from balance in yourDBContect.Balances
            join material in yourDBContect.MaterialsInfos on balance.MaterialsId equals material.Id
            join income in yourDBContect.Incomes on material.Id equals income.MaterialsId
            join bill in yourDBContect.BillOfLadings on income.BillOfLadingId equals bill.Id
            where Balances.GroupBy(g => g.MaterialsId)
                          .Select(s => new
                          {
                               MaterialsId = s.Key,
                               MaxDate = s.Max(x => x.Date)
                          }).ToList().Contains(new { balance.MaterialsId, MaxDate = balance.Date })
            && Incomes.Join(BillOfLadings,
                            p => p.BillOfLadingId,
                            e => e.Id,
                            (p, e) => new { p, e })
                      .GroupBy(g => g.p.MaterialsId)
                      .Select(s => new
                      {
                          MaterialsId = s.Key,
                          MaxDate = s.Max(s => s.e.Date)
                      }).ToList().Contains(new { income.MaterialsId, MaxDate = balance.Date })
            select new
            {
                material.Id,
                balance.Count,
                balance.Cost,
                balance.Name,
                balance.Price,
                balance.Unity,
                ICount = income.Count,
                ICost = income.Cost,
                bill.Date,
                bill.Type,
                bill.Number
            });
```

**Notes:**

- Alias for `Income.Count` and `Income.Cost` are changed because an object cannot contain exactly same nenter code hereamed property.
- Linq for a proper subquery will replace `new List<int>()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. 
In both subqueries I'm trying to select rows with the max date. In first, I need those rows from Balances table, and there are many rows with the same MaterialsInfoId and different Date in this table.
In second, the same thing but with Incomes. Moreover, there is no Date column in Incomes table, so I can get date only from BillOfLadings table.
I added diagram with these tables, maybe it helps to understand by database and my problem)

Comment: This query works for my in SQLServer, so I can't understand the problem with group by column

Comment: Edited. Please recheck. If this doesn't work, then we'll simulate the whole scenario.